# Car won't start with jump but making starting sound

Tags: battery, ignition

Our `Mazda 3` wouldn't respond to the power lock and, when I opened it with the key, it wouldn't even make a click trying to start it. When I jump started it using our `Toyota Tacoma`, it would start making ignition sound but never actually start.

Is the battery likely dead and needs replacement or could't it something downstream in the ignition lifecycle? Could the battery be a mismatch (car vs truck)?

Answer (score 1):

Give us more info please. Was the car running okay days before, did something happened? Usually few things are needed for car to start: Battery, timing, fuel, air, compression. If the car was running perfectly the day before and you just forgot headlights. Then most likely the problem is the car/battery you take power to jump start it, gives not enough power.

Comment: If it's cranking (making the starting sound), then there's enough power to start the engine.

Comment: It's cranking with a jump but nothing with a jump

Comment: @BrydonGibson that's not the case if the car is with diesel engine sometimes the fuel can't reach needed pressure and car won't start even if it's cranking. Sometimes there is too low compression and car won't start once again. That's why I asked for more information.